# Echo this string properly so i have something to study from

Tags: php, mysql, string, echo

I have table and i know how to do most of the `echo` strings, BUT when i get a long one that include words, and headings i get lost. So how do i convert this line?

```
<a class="signUpButton" href="#">Sign Up</a>
```

Take this line and get it to work in the below code which is only partial code.

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row->name . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row->monthly . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row->annually . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody>"; 
echo "<tfoot>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<a class='signUpButton','href='#'>";
echo "</a>";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<a class='signUpButton','href='#'>";
echo "</a>";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<a class='signUpButton','href='#'>";
echo "</a>";
echo "</td>";                
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tfoot>";
```

This code here is what i have now.

```
echo "<a class='signUpButton','href='#'>";
```

it does not work either so something is up. only part that works is everything from the `echo` to the `','` it closes fine, im just not able to see my mouse pointer show that indeed it is a link..

P.S. this code above is only a section, the table is huge, and is working except for the minor issues i am having with links and displaying the button words "signup"

Comment: What language is this? PHP? Tag it.

Comment: echoing separate values separated by a comma only works if those are actually separate values – but `"<a class='signUpButton','href='#'>"` is just _one_ text literal, so that’s what you’re outputting – and of course that does not make sense as HTML. And why do you want to output large portions of (static?) HTML code dynamically anyway? You should just write those outside of the PHP blocks.

Comment: Please go read http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: because this inside a query. You can see my demo page at [http://shawktech.com/demo] I am taking multiple column values from separate tables from a database and then output them into a table. using `while ($row = $result->fetch_object())`

Comment: This is an awful way of writing code!

Comment: 1) you can do that with *one* echo 2) you can also use a template engine.

Comment: Yea your telling me i can do this, But not where i can find this example? I never once have ever written query from a database and echo it into a table. SO I'm sure it is sloppy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but if you need to echo out:

```
<a class="signUpButton" href="#">Sign Up</a>
```

then use:

```
echo '<a class="signUpButton" href="#">Sign Up</a>';
```

or:

```
echo "<a class=\"signUpButton\" href=\"#\">Sign Up</a>";
```

The first method uses single quotes in the echo statement allowing the use of double quotes inside
The second method uses double quotes for the echo statement so uses a \ character to escape the " inside the echo so it doesn't close it.

Comment: They both worked great! Thank you.

Comment: Well it worked great but turns out that i really did not need half the stuff i put in the table to begin with. So now I am stuck with this. `echo "<td>" . $row->name . "</td>";` i have to put what you wrote up top and mix it together. what this code is doing is `echo` a DB column called `name` into a table which has a signup button at the end of the last row. I did enter the code above but it repeated the signup button down all rows.